# Is instance of squalize model have update method?

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Is this code is valid or not?

```
    models.X.findOne({
       where: {
         id:bla
       }
    })
    .then(x => {
      // TODO: check if this will work or not?
      x
        .update({
          someProp: someVal
        })
        .then(() => {});
    });
```

I checked the docs and it says that update is a public static method so I think this code works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
models.X.findOne({
    where: {
        id:bla
    } ,
    // raw : true // <--- Don't use this one , or else you will not get instance of model
}); // <--- This will return the instance of the X
```

**Yes you can do the**

```
x.update({ someProp: someVal });
```